# How to highlight all of the ocurrences of a specific substring in cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been using the below, however found that it only highlights/changes the font color of the first substring per cell. How do I make sure it also highlights subsequent ones?

```
Sub test4String2color()
    Dim strTest As String
    Dim strLen As Integer
    strTest = Range("F1")
    strLen = Len(strTest)
    For Each cell In Range("A1:D100")
      If InStr(cell, strTest) > 0 Then
       cell.Characters(InStr(cell, strTest), strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
     End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through the string until you cannot find *strTest* anymore. Use the position of the previous find to begin successive searches.

```
Sub test4String2color()
    Dim strTest As String, cell As Range
    Dim strLen As Long, p As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        strTest = .Range("F1")
        strLen = Len(strTest)
        For Each cell In Intersect(.Range("A1:D100"), .UsedRange)
            p = InStr(1, cell, strTest)
            Do While CBool(p)
               cell.Characters(p, strLen).Font.Color = vbRed
                p = InStr(p + 1, cell, strTest)
            Loop
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```